# Apps not compatible with original iPad Mini

Tags: xcode, download, app-store, compatibility, ipad-mini

Went to download one of our shipped apps on our iPad Mini 1 and it says "This app is not compatible with your device." The iPad model is PD537LL/A. The App Store lists as compatible devices for our app everything from the iPhone 5S (don't know why this wouldn't be compatible with iPhone 5 or iPhone 4 either) and newer and from iPad Air and iPad Mini 2 and newer.

The app has a minimum deployment target of 8.0 and the iPad Mini is running 9.3.5

In Build Settings > Valid Architectures, the app was archived and submitted with "arm64 armv7 armv7s" listed. It was submitted using Xcode 8.1

I am able to build the app to the original iPad Mini device from Xcode and it runs as expected.

What makes the apps not downloadable from the App Store on original iPad Minis, iPhone 4, and iPhone 5 (before S) devices?

Thanks for any help understanding this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was "Build Active Architecture Only" was set to Yes for release which included only arm64 and ignored the valid architectures setting which included armv7